# Force open/save dialog for all files in a document library (SharePoint 2007)

Tags: document-library

I'm trying to force open/save dialog for all files in a document library, how can i achieve this?

What i've trying until now:
  - document library -> definitions -> advanced definitions -> open in client application
  - IIS -> MIME TYPES -> set some as application/octet-stream

Thanks,
David Esteves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i couldn't find any option at SharePoint, to disable the default behavior. So i just override it with jquery.

Basically SharePoint has a page called download.aspx (located at 12 hive -> LAYOUTS -> Layouts) this page allows to download a file specified in a query string parameter (SourceURL).

The following script must be used at the page containing the library ex: AllItems.aspx

```
<script type="text/jscript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[onclick*='DispEx']").each( function(data){
        var href = this.href;
        this.href = '/divisaojuridica/portal/pedidos/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceURL=' + this.href;
    });
    $("a[onclick*='DispEx']").removeAttr('onclick');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why?

Do you mean prompt the user to save the file, you don't want it to open automatically in Office?

Just for a library or for your entire site/web app? There's a setting in central admin where you can disable client connectivity, which will simply treat documents like links to open a file, with no integration in SP. However this is a web app setting, not site collection or library.

Comment: Yes, i mean prompt the user to save the file, not only office files, but also any type of file, images, pdfs...
I also want to affect every document library in the web application.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: (from memory, forgive me if i'm off) In Central Admin > Application Settings > Authentication Providers, select your zone and there is a setting in there for Client Connectivity., Uncheck that and see if that works for you

If you can't find it, let me know and I'll get into a SP2007 box.

Comment: Nop, i tried but no results. I think it has a slightly different purpose.

It can be somehow related with the DispEx javascript function: 

http://www.siolon.com/blog/adding-edit-dialog-to-a-data-form-web-part/

I'll try to add a dataform to check if the dialog pops-up.

Comment: Ok, then I think it might be up to the individual browsers, there's a setting in Windows or IE to say open certain file types, or prompt to download.